# System.Environment.NewLine no longer recognized in my mails

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I send emails through the class defined below. This worked fine for some years but recently i made a minor change (changed the way i set the host and the port used as showned in the code: smtpClient.Port and  smtpClient.Host).
I'm not sure if this a coincidence bu now my new lines are no longer included in the messages that are sent out.
 The entire mail arrives as a single line. Does anyone have a clue how i may sort this out?

```
public class Email
    {

        private string from;

        private string to;

        private string cc = null;

        private string bcc;

        private string subject;

        private string body;

        private string displayname;


        public string From
        {
            get { return from; }
            set { from = value; }
        }

        public string To
        {
            get { return to; }
            set { to = value; }
        }

        public string Cc
        {
            get { return cc; }
            set { cc = value; }
        }

        public string Bcc
        {
            get { return bcc; }
            set { bcc = value; }
        }

        public string Subject
        {
            get { return subject; }
            set { subject = value; }
        }

        public string Body
        {
            get { return body; }
            set { body = value; }
        }

        public string DisplayName
        {
            get { return displayname; }
            set { displayname = value; }
        }

        public void Send()
        {

            MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
            message.From = new MailAddress(from);
            message.To.Add(new MailAddress(to));
            message.Body = body;
            message.Subject = subject;
            message.IsBodyHtml = true;

            if (cc != null) message.CC.Add(new MailAddress(cc));

            SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
            smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            **smtpClient.Host = smtpClient.Host;// System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SMTPHost"];
            smtpClient.Port = smtpClient.Port;// Convert.ToInt32(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SMTPPort"]);**
            smtpClient.Send(message);






        }
```

Here is how i send messages:

```
Email message= new Email();
message.To=("me@atmytestdomain.com");
message.Subject = "test";
message.From = ("NoReply@atmytestdomain.com");
message.Body = "New line is now omitted"+System.Environment.NewLine;
message.Body += "New line is now omitted"+System.Environment.NewLine;
message.Body += "New line is now omitted"+System.Environment.NewLine;
message.Send();
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: where are you populating body?

Comment: [Talk about MVCE][1]. You appear to be sending out an HTML email, and all newlines are basically ignored in HTML documents. 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: If you are sending HTML emails `Environment.NewLine` will never have produced a line break on its own as far as I know. In HTML a linebreak is just whitespace and will not be rendered as a new line - for that you need a `<br>` tag. Did you definitely not change from nonHTML to HTML at the same time? I will note that HTML as read by email clients seems to be sometimes a law unto itself so it is possible that it does stupid things like line breaks. The other possibility is that the mail server may be doing something with your emails to transform them in some way.

Comment: No, and this is what puzzles me. This has worked as expected for years

Comment: It's a daft question but: are you *certain* that's all that's changed? Did you change the host or port at the same time? Did you set it to html?

Comment: Setting to html has not been touched